# "Use of unresolved identifier 'Realm'"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm, carthage

I installed Realm using Carthage onto my iOS app target (I made sure that I added it to Embedded Binaries section, set the framework search paths, and setup the `copy-frameworks` build phase). I also have an `import RealmSwift` statement at the top of each file where I use it.

Despite this, anywhere I reference Realm or Realm types I still get the error: `"Use of unresolved identifier 'Realm'"` or `"Use of unresolved identifier '<a realm type>'"`.

The weird thing is that my app builds and runs without any issues; the errors disappear while the app is running and reappear when it isn't.

Things I have already tried: selecting Product > Clean, deleting the derived data, restarting Xcode, and restarting the computer—nothing works.

[image: "Use of unresolved identifier 'Realm'" error in Xcode]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [rdar://23551273](http://www.openradar.me/23551273), which affects debugging with precompiled frameworks. It's also discussed at length in Carthage issue [#924](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/924).

I suggest that you use `carthage update --no-use-binaries` to work around this.